# Determine the radius of convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(z-1)^{n}$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: analysis

I'm preparing for exams. Are there any improvements which could be made to my writing?

> Determine the radius of convergence and the convergence area of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(z-1)^{n}$ for $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

First in order to determine the radius of convergene we're going to apply the ratio test. We find by simplifying $|\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}(z-1)^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(z-1)^{n}}|=|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}(z-1)$|. The limit of $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ is one, thus we find that the limt of the ratio is nothing but $|z-1|$. The radius of convergence is one because for $|z-1|<1$ we have convergence and for $|z-1|>1$ the series diverges. In order to determine the convergence area we look at the boundaries. For $z=1$ the series becomes the null series and converges. For $z=0$ the series also converges, because notice that it becomes $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} (-1)^{n}$. The sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to zero and is monotonically decreasing and by the leibniz criteria we find that the series converges. Thus the area of convergence is $|z-1| \leq 1$

Comment: It can be made more concise if you cite [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius).

Comment: At the boundary you should look at $z\in\{0,2\}$, not $z\in\{1, 0\}$. In particular you will find that the series diverges like $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ for $z=2$.

Comment: I cannot belive it, the one and only Maximilian Janisch helps me with math xD

Comment: I see the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of convergence is $1$, since it follows from the ratio test that the series converges when $|z-1|<1$ and that it diverges when $|z-1|>1$. If $z=2$, then the series diverges too, since then what you get is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$, which diverge. And, if $|z-1|=1$ and $z\ne2$, the series converges, by Dirichlet's test.